# MyEtherWaller - Ledger - 'insufficient funds' when I do have ETH in there?

Tags: myetherwallet

Can anyone help on this? I have a Nano Ledger with some ETH on it. I then sent some ECR20 tokens to my Ledger via the MyEtherWallet webpage.  Now trying to withdraw them and it's saying 'insufficient funds' (yet I have plenty of ETH in there - in the Ledger at least, which shows up on the MEW web wallet page) - any ideas where I'm going wrong?! thanks!!﻿  To be clear, the ETH I had on the Ledger before I started using MEW. However the ETH show up when I access MEW. Why does it say insufficient funds?!! thanks

Comment: Is this a transaction you actually submitted? If so, can you point us to the transaction hash? If not, can you share a screenshot of what you're looking at when it says "insufficient funds?"

Comment: If you're just sending tokens, then the gas price * gas limit of the tx must be higher than the amount of ETH in your wallet. if you send ETH then the amount in your wallet must be at least gas price * gas limit + eth transfer value

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you finally did your transactions successfully but for the people passing by and needing help as well:

If you indeed have enough funds and you get this message, yes it happens sometimes on MEW. Just wait few minutes and check your wallet on etherscan to be sure no transaction is broadcasted then retry again. No need to refresh the MEW page, just click the button again to generate the transaction and it should work.